# after setting the cr3 register, why does the machine reboot?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel-module

To understand the memory management, I implement a new page table. I insert a module to kernel(this module creates a new page table according to orignal page table), through the ioctl syscall, i can control the process to use the new page table, but when the kernel module execute the `mov %rdi,%cr3`, the machine reboot, I have spent so much time to find why, but I can't solve the problem.
Maybe there are something I understand wrong.

I user qemu's command to check the pte of the page table. So i'm sure the virtual address **0xffffffffc04bca42** can be translate to physical address.
but when i use gdb to debug, after vm execute **0xffffffffc04bca3f**, the vm reboot.

when the address the the next instruction can be right to translate, why the machine reboot? and what should I do to solve this problem?

I'm going crazy about this problem.

```
0xffffffffc04bca2d <ioctl_switchpgd+79>:   callq  0xffffffff810cb7a4 <printk>
0xffffffffc04bca32 <ioctl_switchpgd+84>:   movabs $0xffffffffffffff,%rdi
0xffffffffc04bca3c <ioctl_switchpgd+94>:   and    %rbx,%rdi
0xffffffffc04bca3f <ioctl_switchpgd+97>:   mov    %rdi,%cr3
**0xffffffffc04bca42 <ioctl_switchpgd+100>:  nopl   0x0(%rax)**
0xffffffffc04bca46 <ioctl_switchpgd+104>:  mov    $0xffffffffc04bd13a,%rdi
```

I upload my code to github, https://github.com/peasentspring/replace_pgd.git. can anyone help me?

Comment: How are you handling the *Reserved* bits? [**CR3 on X86_64**](http://wiki.osdev.org/CPU_Registers_x86-64#CR3)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin  I have been set Reserved bits **Zero**. My Cpu is intel, I know not zero will cause GP.